# Merge EditText and ImageView as a single Image (Bitmap)?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-drawable

I have an **`ImageView`** and an **`EditText`** placed over the **`ImageView`**. I want the written text on **`EditText`** to be a part of **`ImageView`** as a single image (bitmap) as it is being shown while being written. I have tried using **`canvas.drawText(...)`** but couldn't get the exact look while it was being written.

[image]

Update::
**SOLVED ... ANSWER BELOW**

Comment: What do you mean by "as a single image (bimap)" ? Are you trying to save this as an image?

Comment: Yes, But I have solved this one. thnx @Henry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved this. If the image I want is like :

[image]

Then the solution will be :

```
    /**
 * Merging Two Images into One Image.
 * @param baseImage Bitmap as Lower Image , Image to be appeared underneath.
 * @param headerImage Bitmap as Upper Image, Image to be appeared upon the lower image.
 * @return finalImage Bitmap as bytes having both images merged.
 */
public static byte[] mergeImages(Bitmap baseImage, Bitmap headerImage, Bitmap footerImage ) {
    Bitmap finalImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(baseImage.getWidth(), baseImage.getHeight(), baseImage.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(finalImage);
    canvas.drawBitmap(baseImage, new Matrix(), null);

    if(headerImage != null){
        canvas.drawBitmap(headerImage, new Matrix(), null);
    }


    if(footerImage != null){
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setTranslate(0, baseImage.getHeight() - footerImage.getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(footerImage, matrix, null);
    }


    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    finalImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I made something similar you are trying to. I used Textview to do that. I set it's background resource and text seperately.

```
//for image
 int pos = imageList[mPosition];//integer array keeps r.mipmap.x
 tvShare.setBackgroundResource(pos);

//for text you can change settings
 tvShare.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
 tvShare.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

//how I converted it to bitmap
Bitmap image;

image = loadBitmapFromView(tvShare,getApplicationContext());
```